# Python Time Series Dickey-Fuller ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

I'm attempting to perform a Time Series analysis, and in the process I'm performing the Dickey Fuller Test to check for stationarity of my data frame.

I keep getting the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. I have removed any rows with `NaN`'s from the dataframe. The only thing I can think of is the `dftest[0:4]` (in line 4 of the below code), and the `dftest[4]` (in line 6). I don't know what these values mean, which may be causing the error. I've tried shift tab to get an explanation but nothing is helpful. I've also tried `dftest[0:1]` which didn't work. FYI my data frame is only 2 columns

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
def test_stationarity(homepriceTS):

    #Determing rolling statistics
    rolmean = pd.rolling_mean(homepriceTS, window=12)
    rolstd = pd.rolling_std(homepriceTS, window=12)

    #Plot rolling statistics:
    orig = plt.plot(homepriceTS, color='blue',label='Original')
    mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color='red', label='Rolling Mean')
    std = plt.plot(rolstd, color='black', label = 'Rolling Std')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title('Rolling Mean & Standard Deviation')
    plt.show(block=False)

    #Perform Dickey-Fuller test:
    print 'Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:'
    dftest = adfuller(homepriceTS, autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
        dfoutput
```

I have been following along with the pretty good time series step by step here:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. Specifically, post code and full traceback of error messages always directly here on SO. Nobody can paste a picture in their IDE.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a proper series to `test_stationarity()`

If your time series is in the following format:

```
ts.head()

            value
month
2015-08-01    120
2015-09-01    130
2015-10-01    133
2015-11-01    178
2015-12-01    135
...
```

**Try this: `test_stationarity(ts['value'])`**

This converts the dataframe into a proper series and is what the function expects. Or you can convert it before passing to the function:

```
ts = ts['value']
ts.head()

month
2015-08-01    120
2015-09-01    130
2015-10-01    133
2015-11-01    178
2015-12-01    135
...
test_stationarity(ts)
```

Though I can't be sure this is your exact problem since there is no example data, I recently experienced the same error message when testing a time series and I can say for sure that passing the unconverted time series will throw the same `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` message.

Answer (score 0):

The line,

`for key,value in dftest[4].items():`

looks to me the only place in the code where unpacking values is necessary. This being the case, `dftest[4].items()` would need to be one of the kinds of items like those on the right sides of these assignments:

```
>>> k,v = 1,2
>>> k,v = 2,[3,4,5]
>>> k,v = [1,2], [3,4,5]
>>> k,v = [1,2], {2: 3}
```

If I were in your position I'd print `dftest[4].items()` just ahead of that for-loop, to see what kind of a structure it is. (Hazarding a guess I'd say it's a list.) Or, look again at the doc.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the minor code changes that I have made:

## Importing few libraries

```
 import statsmodels.api as sm
    from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, kpss
    def test_stationarity(timeseries):
```

## For Dickey-Fuller's Test

```
 print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
    dftest=adfuller(timeseries,autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput=pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
    print(dfoutput)

test_stationarity(ts)
```

Hoping this would help.